# OpenGL ES 2 inheriting issues

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es2

I am Having an issue where one of my classes will not inherit the other ones variable value. In the class which is inherited. It shows the value of the float just fine. But when I go to the Class which is inheriting the float from that class. the float is 0. example:

```
public class PlayerMode(){
    protected float[] mModelView;

    protected PlayerMode(){
        mModelView = new float[16];
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelView, 0);
    }

    protected void setxPosition(float x){
        mModelView[12] = x;
        Log.d("PlayerMode", String.valueOf(mModelView[12])); //Which equals 3
    }
}


public class PlayerModel extends PlayerMode {
    public void draw(){
       //Draw Stuff...
       Matrix.multiplyMM(mvp, 0, mMvpMatrix, 0, mModelView, 0);
       Log.d("PlayerModel", String.valueOf(mModelView[12])); //Which equals 0  
    }
}
```

I have tryed making a method in PlayerMode that returns mModelView[12] to PlayerModel but with no results. I can also see this as the object I am drawing is not moving at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how [inheritance in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) works at all.

You do not inherit the value, that doesn't make any sense.

Simply put you inherit data members (the variables) and methods (the functions), that's all.

Don't use the PlayerMode class directly, use your PlayerModel class.
You can call the setxPosition method there since it's inherited and your value will be set in the instance of PlayerModel you are using.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my ignorance. I'll be going over the Java syntax some more. But thank you.